# Use scientific notation with xtable in R

Tags: r

I pass a data.frame to xtable

```
 dat.table <- xtable(dat[1:20,] ,digits=10)
```

Instead of displaying digits like that, I would prefer to use scientific notation. How would I do that?

had a look but all I found was [R: formatting the digits in xtable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8652731/r-formatting-the-digits-in-xtable) which isn't the answer it seems.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try:

```
dat.table <- xtable(dat[1:20,] ,digits=-10)
```

"If values of digits are negative, the corresponding values of x are displayed in scientific format with abs(digits) digits." [xtable](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/xtable/docs/xtable)

Comment: I must have missed that line in the help.. Thanks!

Comment: This produces `2.0000000000E-01` instead of `\(2 \cdot 10^{-1}\)`. I cannot think when that would ever be appropriate. :-(

Comment: then use `digits=-3`.

Answer (score 8):

If you are wanting to x10^ notation trying use `print` and `xtable`. something like:

`print(xtable(dat[1:10,1:7], display=c("s","s", "s","s","g","g","g","g")), math.style.exponents = TRUE)`

where s is string and g is used for scientific notation (only when space is saved), the`math.style.exponents` from `print` will convert to x10^format.