# Formatting scientific notation for latex

Tags: r

In RStudio, I get scientific notation results like 1e-2 or 4e-35. I am using xtable to export such numbers to latex but want them to look like in a regular format in latex i.e., `$1 \times 10^{-2}$` or `$4 \times 10^{-35}$`. How can I code in R to get such regular scientific notation format as the xtable output?

Comment: It doesn’t seem that xtable alone can do this. In fact, I don’t think *any* R package does this out of the box, which is just incredibly poor. 

Comment: I am not sure if this solves your issue, but just throwing this out there in case you missed it: [does this help?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27103006/use-scientific-notation-with-xtable-in-r)

Comment: @Florian Great find, but: Wow, that’s almost insultingly bad.   Rather than producing properly-formatted LaTeX numbers, `xtable` creates an abomination such as this: `2.0000000000E-01`.

Comment: A base R hack would be `sapply(strsplit(format(1000, scientific=TRUE), split="e"), function(x) paste0("$", x[1], " \times 10^{", x[2], "}$"))` (replacing the 1000 with the name of the vector to format). You could wrap this in a function and apply it to any columns that you would want to appear with this form of scientific notation.

Comment: @lmo No need t reformat the number, you can just use the LaTeX package ‹siunitx›, and then: `sprintf('\\num{%s}', format(numbers))` ([with an appropriate `\sisetup`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/269848/42)); in fact, the numbers don’t even have to be `format`ted in R, siunitx does all the work necessary. By the way, `$…$` math delimiters are deprecated in LaTeX; use `\(…\)` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @KonradRudolph. I didn't know about that package.

Comment: I don't know how wedded you are to xtable; if you're not wedded to it, the `huxtable` package makes pretty tables that are compatible with LaTeX very easily (the [package website](https://hughjonesd.github.io/huxtable/) has examples).